# Stristr not finding needle in haystack

Tags: php, html

Why is the originalString not being found in the childString?

```
<?php
$originalString='<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
   Hey, <br>
   <br>
Here\'s the dump, email me the final version so I can write up the
email for the rest of the team. Feel free to review it and let me
know if you think I should change anything, I tried to keep it
simple and functional, but I\'m not a data guy like yourself. :P<br>
<br>
Thanks a ton!<br>
<div class="moz-signature">-- <br>
  <span style="font-weight:heavy;font-style:italic;float:left;"><br>
    Josh Someone<br>
    Creative Developer<br>
    <br>
    Someplace Studios<br>
    New Media Marketing Company<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    Phone Number: 1-(555) 555-5555<br>
    Website: <a class="moz-txt-link-freetext" href="http://www.someplace.com">http://www.someplace.com</a><br>
  </span></div>
  </body>
 </html>
';

$childString = '<html>
  <head>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    http-equiv="Content-Type">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <div class="moz-cite-prefix">On 1/22/2013 5:05 PM,
     <a class="moz-txt-link-abbreviated"     href="mailto:jonathan@someplace.com">jonathan@someplace.com</a> wrote:<br>
    </div>
    <blockquote cite="mid:20130122170541.33321jbg8uoshnhx@someplace.com"
     type="cite">Nothing was attached.
     <br>
  <br>
  Quoting Josh Someone <a class="moz-txt-link-rfc2396E" href="mailto:josh@someplace.com">&lt;josh@someplace.com&gt;</a>:
  <br>
  <br>
  <blockquote type="cite">Hey,
    <br>
    <br>
    Here\'s the dump, email me the final version so I can write up
    the email for the rest of the team. Feel free to review it and
    let me know if you think I should change anything, I tried to
    keep it simple and functional, but I\'m not a data guy like
    yourself. :P
    <br>
    <br>
    Thanks a ton!
    <br>
    --&nbsp;<br>
    <br>
    Josh Someone
    <br>
    Creative Developer
    <br>
    <br>
    Someplace Studios
    <br>
    New Media Marketing Company
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    Phone Number: 1-(555) 555-5555
    <br>
    Website: <a class="moz-txt-link-freetext" href="http://www.someplace.com">http://www.someplace.com</a>
    <br>
    <br>
  </blockquote>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</blockquote>
<br>
Bleh.<br>
<br>
<div class="moz-signature">-- <br>
  <span style="font-weight:heavy;font-style:italic;float:left;"><br>
    Josh Someone<br>
    Creative Developer<br>
    <br>
    Someplace Studios<br>
    New Media Marketing Company<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    Phone Number: 1-(555) 555-5555<br>
    Website: <a class="moz-txt-link-freetext" href="http://www.someplace.com">http://www.someplace.com</a><br>
  </span></div>
  </body>
</html> 
 ';

 $replace = array("\r\n"," ");

 $originalText = str_replace($replace,'',strip_tags($originalString));
 $childText    = str_replace($replace,'',strip_tags($childString));

  // $originalText =    trim(str_replace(array('\r\n','\n','\r'),'',strip_tags($originalString)));
  // $childText    = trim(str_replace(array('\r\n','\n','\r'),'',(strip_tags($childString)));

 if(stristr($childText,$originalText)){
         echo "Yes";
  } else {
         echo "No";
 }
```

Comment: `var_dump($originalText, $childString);` --- stop guessing

Comment: string(25) " Hey buddy " string(62) " Hey buddy number two "

Comment: Youve got it backwards. Im searching a 62 char string with a 25 char string

Comment: You've missed `\n` in your output. It's `string(20) "\n \n Hey buddy\n \n \n " string(55) "\n \n Hey buddy number two\n \n\n"`

Comment: add trim() `trim(str_replace('\r\n','',strip_tags($originalString)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$replace = array("\r\n", " ");

$originalText = str_replace($replace,'',strip_tags($originalString));
$childText    = str_replace($replace,'',strip_tags($childString));
```

Comment: "&nbsp" need delete? and &lt; &gt; ...etc

change to 

$replace = array("\r\n", " ", "&nbsp;");

Comment: is there a function that can provide me the htmlentities so i can just pass all of them in?

Comment: $list = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);  $replace = array_merge($replace, $list);